# Настройка DB Navigator в webstorm

Tags: webstorm

Разрабатываю чат на nodeJS(webstorm), необходима база данных, скачал плагин DB Navigator, но база данных не создается, в чем проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: База должна быть установлена в системе. Этот плагин ничего не создаёт сам по себе. На картинке видно, что программа не может подключиться к серверу базы данных, и одна только Ванга знает, что у вас там и вообще есть ли.

Comment: То есть необходимо скачать отдельное приложение для создания базы данных? Не подскажите, как оно называется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по картинке, вам требуется база данных MySQL. Установщик MySQL Community Edition (бесплатная) можно скачать отсюда (mysql-installer-community-8.0.28.0.msi):
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

Установите ее, следуя инструкциям на экране. Дополнительные инструкции можете посмотреть на  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-installation.html, если возникнут трудности.

Далее: на выходе у вас будет учетная запись root  с паролем, который вы сами укажете во время установки.

Далее, уже в MySQL вам нужно будет создать нужную базу данных.

В своей программе вам надо будет указать:

1. host: 127.0.0.1
2. port: 3306
3. database: имя вашей созданной ранее базы
4. user: root
5. password: ваш пароль

После этого, ваш WebStorm уже сможет подключиться к локальной программе баз данных.
Ну а потом создавайте нужную вам структуру таблиц в вашей базе.